# SassError: can't properly access theme-color()

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Full Error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/@core/scss/react/libs/noui-slider/noui-slider.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-0-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-0-4!./src/@core/scss/react/libs/noui-slider/noui-slider.scss)
SassError: $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color.
   ╷
23 │     "lighten-5": lighten(theme-color("primary"), 25%),
   │                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src/@core/scss/base/core/colors/palette-variables.scss 23:18  @import
  src/@core/scss/base/core/colors/palette-noui.scss 11:9        @import
  src/@core/scss/react/libs/noui-slider/noui-slider.scss 3:9    root stylesheet
```

To be clear, once I switched all occurrences of `theme-color("primary")` to the actual color(#0074d9, blue color I found from Bootstrap documentation which is the supposed primary color) across the SCSS files, it then gave me the same error for `theme-color("secondary")` which were in proceeding lines of the files. I'm working off a template and this is the import at the top of the files this error is coming from:

```
// Overrides user _variables-components
@import '../../bootstrap-extended/include';
```

This leads to the following file presumably made by the template maker:

```
// Functions
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions'; // Bootstrap core function
@import 'functions'; // Bootstrap extended function

// Variables
@import 'scss/variables/variables'; // Bootstrap custom variable override (for user purpose)
@import 'variables'; // Bootstrap extended variable override
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables'; // Bootstrap core variable

// Mixins
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins'; // Bootstrap core mixins
@import 'mixins'; // Bootstrap extended mixins
```

package.json:

```
"bootstrap": "5.1.3",
"sass-loader": "^12.2.0"
```

Maybe I should downgrade bootstrap? Should I try to override the variables that don't work in my `palette-variables.scss` file under `$theme-colors` like some articles recommend despite the theme already trying to do that?

I haven't yet gotten this react project up and running locally, which is the goal, and this seems to be the last group of errors to plow through before getting the development server running since when running `npm start` it'd say "starting up the development server", open up localhost:3000 and almost work.

Comment: Well apparently your `theme-color()` function is not called. Is it defined anywhere? Did you miss to import it before the first usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used yarn to install the modules and everything worked completely fine.